# Need assistance understanding terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, terraform

I am not sure if I am able to understand the code perfectly please help me out here. This is the code I have I am not understand what is Azure Active Directory doing here and what is the purpose of vault.

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "client_id" {
  path = var.settings.client_id
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "client_secret" {
  path = var.settings.client_secret
}

# Display a secret client for Azure Service Principal
output "secret" {
  value = data.vault_generic_secret.client_id.data["client_id"]
}


locals {
  vault_client_id     = data.vault_generic_secret.client_id.data["client_id"]
  vault_client_secret = data.vault_generic_secret.client_secret.data["client_secret"]

  settings_with_secrets = merge(var.settings, {
    client_id     = local.vault_client_id
    client_secret = local.vault_client_secret
  })

}


resource "aws_cognito_identity_provider" "universal_provider" {

  user_pool_id  = var.user_pool_id
  provider_name = var.provider_name
  provider_type = var.provider_type

  provider_details = local.settings_with_secrets

  attribute_mapping = var.attribute_mappings

  # We use this to avoid changes to this every execution as described here: 
  # https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4831
  # https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4807
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      provider_details["attributes_url"],
      provider_details["attributes_url_add_attributes"],
      provider_details["authorize_url"],
      provider_details["token_request_method"],
      provider_details["token_url"],
      provider_details["oidc_issuer"]
    ]
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAD doesn't do anything here.

The Vault provider allows Terraform to read from, write to, and configure [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/?_ga=2.263173963.63148673.1620372165-1511703467.1615797884). Reference [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs).

So the script reads the client id and client secret (which are stored in the HashiCorp Vault) of an Azure service principal. Reference [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/data-sources/generic_secret).

Then put them into the `locals` Values as `settings_with_secrets` for later use.

At last, it [provides a Cognito User Identity Provider resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_identity_provider) with AAD as the provider by setting its client id and client secret in `provider_details`.